# Can Bloc be used in StatefullWidget to use SingleTickerProviderStateMixin? (I'm kinda new)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, bloc, cubit

I'm using a TabBarController and as u know we should extend SingleTickerProviderStateMixin which is available only for StatefullWidget..

I'm using Bloc in my app so I can optimize the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, you can accomplish this using **Bloc State Management** if you want.

And also there is a full implementation of `Tabbar with Bloc` in this link: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/549

Comment: how about animation? i made a custom FAB that spin and stuff, and the only way ik how to make this work is to put functions in the initState fn